# Geotiffs on Geoserver - Alpha?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, transparency-opacity

I'm having a hard time dealing with geotiff images on a geoserver: I can't seem to get rid of the black 'no data' background around my geotiff image (a map area with a transparent background).

Further clarification: the geoTiff is in a geoserver layer group, and not a layer of its own, and it has the geoserver 'default' raster style on it (nothing but an opacity setting).

By default, my colour image is a black and white one; I can set the colour channels through the layer style, but that strips the alpha info (as I read elsewhere).

Setting the 'transparent colour' (to #000000) in the geoserver layer specifications doesn't seem to work, either.

I also see a place in the layer-specific page where we can set the channels/bands (there are five in mine, but the first four are rgba, verified by gdalinfo) to certain values (range, 'unit' (?)), but I can find no documentation on this.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Which GeoServer version? What is the bit depth of your GeoTiff? Did you try using JAI-Ext? Is the nodata value set in the GeoTiff?

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer can only make use of the Alpha Channel when the GeoTiff has 4 channels (RGBA). Similarly, `OutputTransparentColor` only works on RGB / RGBA 8 bit images.

As your GeoTiff has 5 channels, your best bet is to add a [layer mask](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html#internal_mask) to your GeoTiffs.

```
gdal_translate ... -mask the_mask.tif ...
```

Or [add vector footprints](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/raster_data/imagemosaic_footprint.html) as sidecar files (.shp or .wkt).

Note: You will also need to [select the RGB channels in the Style](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#channelselection).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the program I was editing the image in was adding a 'mystery channel/bamd' right after the rgb bands, which bumped the alpha channel to the fifth slot, and geoserver took the fourth one (the 'mystery band' that had a 255 value for every pixel) for the alpha.

An oversight on my behalf (and perhaps a problem other than geotiff/geoserver), but perhaps this note about this behaviour might be useful to others with a similar problem.

I managed to find what was causing the 'mystery channel' and remove it, and, lo, the geotiff behaved normally (with the server style set to only an 'opacity' command).

Answer (score -1):

Pre-processing the GeoTiff with *gdalwarp* has worked for me:

```
gdalwarp -of Gtiff -dstalpha input.tif output.tif
```

From [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html):

> -dstalpha: Create an output alpha band to identify nodata (unset/transparent) pixels.

Comment: see my answer: this does only work for RGB, which is not the case here. And referring to the Question, OP already has an alpha band